# Ionic 1 on iOS Xcode Problems when doing HTTP POST Request

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, xcode, ionic-framework

I have a problem while making HTTP post request, I'm creating REST Api with ExpressJS with CORS Activated. But, it's working fine if I'm requesting to HTTPS server.

Problem Scenario:

- POST::Request to HTTP (Node.js not receiving any body request from req.body) -> {}
- POST::Request to HTTPS (Node.js receiving body request from req.body) > {data: blablabla}

Build Tools:

- Xcode 8
- iOS 10

What I've been trying:

- Add SCP meta tag in index.html
- Add domain exception list to *-Info.plist in NSDomainExceptions
- Specify {headers: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
- Allow HTTP services in developer mode of iPhone

If any of you had similar problems and already fixed it, please help me to solve this :) Thank you.